# stacked bar *bringing labels to the graph *

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a stacked bar graph and use geom_text to insert the value and name of each stack. The problem is some stacks are very small/narrow, so that the text of two stacks overlap each other and hence is not very readable. How can I modify the code to solve this issue.

```
 Type<-c("ddddddddddd","ddddddddddd","bbbbbbbbbbbbb","ddddddddddd","eeeeeeeeeeeeee","bbbbbbbbbbbbb","ddddddddddd","bbbbbbbbbbbbb","ddddddddddd",
        "eeeeeeeeeeeeee","mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm","bbbbbbbbbbbbb","ddddddddddd","bbbbbbbbbbbbb","eeeeeeeeeeeeee")
        Category<-c("mmmmm","mmmmm","gggggggggggggggggg","ffffffffffff","ffffffffffff","ffffffffffff","sanddddddddd","sanddddddddd","yyyyyyyyyyy",
        "yyyyyyyyyyy","yyyyyyyyyyy","sssssssssssssss","sssssssssssssss","sssssssssssssss","ttttttttttttt")
        Frequency<-c(4,1,30,7,127,11,1,1,6,9,1,200,3,4,5)
        Data <- data.frame(Type, Category, Frequency)   
        p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Type, y = Frequency)) +
          geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat="identity", show.legend = FALSE) +
          geom_text(aes(label = Frequency), size = 3) +
          geom_text(aes(label = Category), size = 3)
```

Comment: You could pad either Frequency or Category (e.g. `aes(label = Category, y = Frequency + 10)`). For the second column, you're probably out of luck since it's very crowded. Another option would perhaps be directlabels http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

Considering your data, a facetted plot might be a better approach:

```
# summarise your data
library(dplyr)
d1 <- Data %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(substr(.,1,2)),Type,Category) %>%
  group_by(Type,Category) %>% 
  summarise(Freq = sum(Frequency)) %>%
  mutate(lbl = paste(Category,Freq)) # create a label by pasting the 'Category' and the 'Freq' variables together

# plot
ggplot(d1, aes(x = Category, y = Freq, fill = Category)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.7, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = lbl), angle = 90, size = 5, hjust = -0.1, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,240)) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(.~Type, scales = "free", space = "free") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14)
```

which gives:

[image]

In the above plot I shortened the labels on purpose. If you don't want to do that, you could consider this:

```
d2 <- Data %>%
  group_by(Type,Category) %>% 
  summarise(Freq = sum(Frequency)) %>%
  mutate(lbl = paste(Category,Freq))

ggplot(d2, aes(x = Category, y = Freq, fill = Category)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.7, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 5, label = lbl), alpha = 0.6, angle = 90, size = 5, hjust = 0, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,240)) +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(.~Type, scales = "free", space = "free") +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

which gives:

[image]